# How to downgrade Node version on Linode Server connected with Forge?

Tags: deployment, nuxt.js, devops, forge, linode

I've a Linode server which I control using Forge, I've connected my Github repo with Forge and I go to command page at forge to run the deploy commands.

when I run `yarn build` I got error message says `The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "14.16.1". Got "18.16.0"`, I tried to use nvm but it's not installed on forge commands and I don't know how to install with forge commands.

**My main question is** how to downgrade node engine version through forge commands page or through Linode server page ?

My tries:

1- I've tried to install nvm by running `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash` on forge web interface but it says `close and reopen the terimanl to use nvm` and I ran `exit` and tried `nvm -v` which shows nvm not found.

2- I've used ssh to login into server I ran all the commands to install nvm and downgrade to node version 14.16.1 but on the forge web interface page nothing shows to be fixed nvm is still not found and node version is still as before at version 18.